# What Is The "Wharf cache default layout" In Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

From the Artifactory documentation at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts#RepositoryLayouts-BundledLayouts

> Bundled Layouts
>
> Artifactory comes out-of-the-box with a number of default, predefined
> layouts requiring no additional configuration:
>
> ```
> Maven 2/3
> Ivy (default layout)
> Gradle (Wharf cache default layout)
> Maven 1
> ```

What is this "Wharf cache default layout" linked to Gradle?

I can access Maven Central perfectly fine with Gradle so I am confused about what this extra layout is.

Is this Gradle layout identical to a Maven 2/3 layout or is it something else?

If I choose `Gradle (Wharf cache default layout)` in Artifactory, can I access it with both Gradle **and** Maven or is there something different about it that restricts it to only Gradle use?

If it does restrict use to Gradle only, why would you use it? (since that appear to make it have fewer features than the Maven 2/3 layout)

If Maven can access it too, why would you use it? (as it seems redundant)

Is there some performance boost or some other difference that is a reason to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Maven is the name for both a build tool and a repository type, while Gradle is only a build tool.  Gradle can work against Maven, Gradle, and Ivy repositories.

According to [JFrog docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Working+with+Gradle#WorkingwithGradle-ConfiguringArtifactory) Artifactory can be used as the Gradle build cache by simply creating a generic repository in Artifactory. The Wharf cache default layout which was introduced back in Gradle 1.0 and I believe it was meant as a way for caching local cache in a shared manner. Yet this was long ago, and though the layout does remain there, the way Gradle repos work is more adaptive to their use case:

[image: This is the current Artifactoru "set me up"]

You can now define a layout for each part; plugins resolver, libs resolver, or libs publisher. Gradle being a build tool, and not repository type, needs a private registry that can adapt, and Artifactory makes it really easy to set up.

Comment: So are you saying that the Wharf cache doesn't do anything different and it is just the "Set Me Up" that changes to generate Gradle settings?